# What would be the best form of martial arts for a bigger guy?

Tags: training, mixed-martial-arts, weight

I am 6”3 and 256 pounds, I played sports my whole life so I’m not fat but I do have a few extra pounds on right now that I just started working on losing again. After I get down to 230-240 I wanted to start working on a martial art that would fit my body type. When I was 315 I was still able to duck and weave punches when sparing and return combos back. I bench around 325 and squat 585 so strength and speed for my size isn’t a problem. I just would like to start getting some ideas of styles to look into.

Comment: Not a bad question. Truthfully, there are very few martial arts you can't do with your size. How is your flexibility? What do you want to get out of martial arts? Is it for getting stronger? Deadlier? To pick up Karate chicks? Do you have strong feelings on striking versus grappling? Do you want to learn how to fight rather than how to perform? And what martial arts are available in your area?

There's a good for asking these questions at https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/506/a-good-martial-art-recommendation-question-guidelines.